# React Native: Change and keep the background color of only onPressed item inside Flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've manage to change the background color of the onPressed button inside a Flatlist by assigning item.id to the state. My issue is that when I press another button the previously pressed button changes back to the initial backgroundcolor. How can I keep the new backgoundcolor even when I press another button?

```
 onPressButtonarrived(item.id) {
    this.setState({ disablearrived: item.id })
    this.setState({ colorarrived: item.id })
  }


<View style={{backgroundColor: item.id === this.state.colorarrived ? '#D6D6D6' : '#E5C454'}}>
    <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {this.onPressButtonarrived(item.id)}} disabled={item.id === this.state.disablearrived ? true : false}>
    <Text>Arrival</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Can you please post the whole code here. It might help me. I can't understand whats happening in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have some values on state for each item:

```
 onPressButtonarrived(item.id) {
        this.setState({ [item.id +'-disablearrived']: !this.state[item.id] });
        this.setState({ [item.id +'-colorarrived']: !this.state[item.id] });
        // that should toggle some true false vars for each item.id 
      }


    <View style={{backgroundColor: this.state[item.id +'-colorarrived'] ? '#D6D6D6' : '#E5C454'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {this.onPressButtonarrived(item.id)}} disabled={!!this.state[item.id +'-disablearrived']}>
        <Text>Arrival</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Works, like a charm! Thanks for that buddy. I had to change !state[item.id] to !this.state[item.id] in the function, but it did the trick!

Comment: I updated the answer with the small `this.state ` adjustment. I am happy the issue is solved.